# How to override Spark default log4j profile in intellij?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am coding spark in IntelliJ with sbt. i tried many tricks to turn off spark warnings.

My code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext, sql}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
object TheObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SimpleApplication").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val data = spark.read.format("csv")
    data.printSchema()
  }
}
```

but the output says:
`Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties`

and no changes.
is there any way to turn it off without changing any file properties?